I am having a hard time setting up Chartboost mediation into my unity project
Their is no other source to understand how to implement the SDK other than the documentation and I tried following the documentation and installed how it is mentioned. But I am unable to integrate and configure it.
To initialize the mediation SDK which is a part of Chartboost core SDK which mean I have to initialize the core SDK which is the part I am having hard time it says to have a CMP which I tried and got to no where.
I tried to use ChatGPT for it but it keeps using the "using ChartboostSDK;" which is not their. I even provide it the documentation in text and still didn't yeild any result.
